# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.10 on MacBook Pro

Tags: boot, uefi, mac, refind

I've installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my MacBook Pro, but now when I try to start the computer I just get a blinking icon that tries to tell me that I haven't got any OS installed. I've heard that rEFInd should be able to solve this problem in some way, but I haven't been able to do so. I'd appreciate some clear instructions on what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a question mark blinking in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Yes! Exacly! Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Did you follow a guide when install Ubuntu?  What version Macbook Pro do you have?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have the 2014 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install refind:

Hold the option key when you turn on your macbook pro.  Select OS X then follow these instructions:

Using OS X

Simply click here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.8.3/refind-bin-0.8.3.zip/download to download the rEFInd program/app

Unzip the file

Open a terminal and goto the location where you unzipped the file ie say you unzipped the file in the Downloads directory you would type cd Downloads, then type ./install.sh this will place the refind on your hard drive.

Reboot and refind will give you the options to select how you want to boot.